# Visualise whole neural network in weka

Tags: neural-network, weka

I built a large neural network in WEKA using MLP and when I try to view it (using the GUI parameter = true) it only shows a small portion of it, with no way of viewing the whole neural net (that I know of).

An example of what I mean is [found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKQ7X.jpg)

any help in viewing the whole network will be much appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This question [has been answered on the Weka mailing list](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Viewing-whole-neural-network-in-WEKA-tp43916p43938.html):

> The GUI has been fixed in the SVN repository so that you can now
>   scroll vertically (and horizontal, if necessary) to inspect the entire
>   network.
>
> The next nightly snapshots (excluding WEKA 3.6) should have the fix.
>   See
>
> https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/snapshots/weka_snapshots.html
>
> for download links.

If you want (or have) to stick to a stable release of Weka, the [previous answer](https://list.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2018-September/073078.html) suggested a workaround:

> In the meantime, you could try a desktop extender. :-) There appears
>   to be one for Windows:
>
> http://www.gimespace.com/gms3d.html